# Realm - Querying long-type class returns empty

Tags: java, android, realm

When querying `equalTo` a field with long type, the RealmResults returns blank. My query code is as below:

```
_realm.beginTransaction();
long albumID = Long.valueOf(albumId);
results = _realm.where(Image.class).equalTo("albumId",albumID).findAll();
_realm.commitTransaction();
```

**albumId** is a string passed by a method

**Image class:**

```
public class Image extends RealmObject {
  @PrimaryKey
  private long id;
  private long albumId;
  private String url;
  private int width;
  private int height;
  private long published;

//Setters and getters
}
```

I tried to query without the `equalTo` and see that the results contain **albumId** values

Comment: Does it return an empty RealmResults or null? It should not return null.

Comment: Also, you don't need a transaction for read operations

Comment: It returns empty array when I output to Logcat. I can remove the transactions wrapping, but the point is it's still working with this query: `results = _realm.where(Image.class).findAll();`

Comment: Are you sure that your calculated albumId is correct and match the one in Ream. You query looks correct otherwise. If you still are having problems I would create a an issue on GitHub so we have a chance of investigating further.

Comment: I am sure about the albumId. I'll create an issue on Github with sample data.